# Pyinstaller and Pandas Error when exporting

Tags: python, pandas, pyinstaller

I have a working project with tkinter and Pandas but whenever I try to export it using Pyinstaller it will show an error when I Import pandas to my project.

```
    57986 WARNING: Cannot read QLibraryInfo output: raised Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) when decoding:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 11, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python36\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 111, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 838, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 784, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 241, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 500, in assemble
    module_hook.post_graph()
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\imphook.py", line 410, in post_graph
    self._load_hook_module()
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\imphook.py", line 377, in _load_hook_module
    self.hook_module_name, self.hook_filename)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 736, in importlib_load_source
    return mod_loader.load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 399, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 823, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 682, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 265, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 684, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-PyQt5.py", line 23, in <module>
    collect_system_data_files(pyqt5_library_info.location['PrefixPath'],
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\qt.py", line 67, in __getattr__
    qli = json.loads(json_str)
  File "c:\python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "c:\python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "c:\python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

This is my Firstime exporting to an exe. I have reinstalled pyinstaller pyqt5, pandas, and still none.
Im using

- Windows 10
- python 3.6
- I used Pip to install the libraries

libraries: pandas, pyinstaller.

Comment: Is this the complete error message (I am confused by the three dots). If not, please post the complete error message. Also, could you please add some more information about what kind of environment this is (Windows? Anaconda? ...)

Answer (score 0):

```
collect_system_data_files(pyqt5_library_info.location['PrefixPath']
```

This shows error started while collecting system data file. Try installing PyQt5 and then run PyInstaller.

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem. After hours of messing around I believe that deleting a older version of python that was on my computer was what fixed it, all though I can't be absolutley sure, since I did many things. I would suggest trying to uninstall other versions of python if you have them, and then uninstalling and reinstalling the dependencies of your program through pip. Then make sure you are able to run your python script `myProgram.py` from the cmd: `C:\<path to the location of myProgram>\>python myProgram.py`. Resolve any errors that might occur before trying to use pyinstaller, which solved this particular error for me.